# Slow search in Discussion Forum

Tags: search, forum

I 'm using Discussion Forum having millions of posts due to which search in forum in much slow. Could anyone please share a way to optimize the forum search.

Thanks,

Comment: Could I see your code?

Comment: How large is your forum? How many entries?

Comment: Its having millions of entries. I am not sure how it can be optimized. Also, I couldn't see any caching solution for it. Please suggest some caching solution also if available for Discussion Forum.